# how can I use old PST file in outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I have several .PST files related to a **MS-Outlook 2010** version.
These files belong to the several accounts in an old MS-Outlook 2010.
I want to use them for a **new installation of MS-Outlook** but when I make a new account (same name before) MS-Outlook make a new .PST file for that account (the Emails recognized as IMAP) and the size of this new .PST is **just 265 KB** but the old one has size  **more than 1GB**

For example, for an account named **client@mycompany.com** it made a file **client@mycompany.com(2).pst**
I want to **replace old .pst file** [client@mycompany.com.pst] **instead** [client@mycompany.com(2).pst]

Any Idea is welcome,,, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you made a typo and use .PST files, you can simply import old .pst files and merge them with whatever outlook made for you.

To do so, go to File -> Import -> Import from a file -> PST file.

Browse to the pst backup file and import it to the root of the new file so that it keeps the structure in tact. It is also possible to import it to a folder, so you can keep the backup separated from the main account.

Alternatively, you can just open the pst file in outlook directly and see it as a mail account where no new mail comes in (for backup/archive purposes).

To do so, Go to File -> Open -> PST file and browse to the .pst file. It will now show on the left side under your accounts.

Comment: Thank you my Friend. It seems good idea, but I have a new problem!
right now any account that I defined in Outlook made a new file with a number.
For example, client@mycompany.com made client@mycompany.com(2).psd and client@mycompany.com(3).psd and client@mycompany.com(4).psd !!!
what is happened?

Comment: Yes, because it has the same name. That's why you create a new outlook profile without the old PST, and then use the import function to get the email, calendar, contacts, tasks, etc out.

Comment: Can I delete all of them and import the old one?

Comment: Yes. But rather than delete, move them out of the folder. That way, if you find out you accidentally deleted the wrong one, it is not actually gone, but just moved. After you're done, you can then safely delete them.

Comment: when I use the Outlook **Automatic** search for server setting then it recognizes all of accounts as IMAP and the wizard don't allow me to choose the exist PSD file (old psd).

in the other hand,If i choose **Manual** search for server setting then I can select POP only and I can choose the old PSD, but I can not send the email, just I can receiving the emails ... :(

Comment: Dear LPChip ,, I done before but Outlook generates a new one with a number one more!! means, when I moved the client@mycompany.com(2).psd and delete it, outlook generates client@mycompany.com(3).psd !!!

Comment: You must both move the file out AND create a new outlook profile. Not just add an account. Also, if the old profile still exists, outlook will obviously keep those files safe. So you must also delete the old profiles.

Comment: @Kasra, you need to setup your account use the manual setup method so that you can choose to use an existing .pst file. The Auto Account Setup wizard will by default create a new .pst file. Try creating a new mail profile via Control Panel and reconfigure your IMAP account via manual setup.

Answer (score 0):

I ran an automatic routine for getting the specification of the desired email.
I should mention here the email was an IMAP email type.

Then, I get **the ports numbers of IMAP email type in my mail-server** (incoming=SSL 995 and outging=SSL 465).

And then, **I ignored the final step** and I canceled the procedure.

Then I started for making a new account (based on the desired email) **but manually**.
In the windows for inserting the details of wanted email, I mentioned **POP3 type** for the email. then **I could set the existing datafile (.pst)** for using as a necessary datafile for this email.

but before going to the final step (pressing "Next" button) I went to **"More Setting ..."** and in **"Advanced"** Tab, I did set the incoming & outgoing port numbers with the specified details **(incoming= SSL, port no.=995 & outgoing=SSL, port no.=465)**

Then I went to the **"Outgoing Server"** Tab and tick the **"My outgoing server (SMTP) ..."** for using same incoming server setting for it.

Then I did click the **"OK" button** and then click the **"Next" button**.

Then I should wait for complete the **"Test Account"** procedure. **Now I have a new email account with using the old .pst datefile.**

After the completion of the setting for a new account, maybe **the account does not show the new emails.**

For solving this problem you can follow the instructions of below picture:

[image]

Comment: Welcome. It's worth noting that all of the server and port settings are unrelated to what needs to be done to re-use an existing PST file when setting up a new account. Mentioning them is more of a distraction than a help.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator _ It seems the ports settings in mail-server are related to this matter. because when I follow the automatic procedure for setting up an email account then I have not the option of using old PST files. And on the other hand, when I follow the manual setting and use the POP3 type emails then the port numbers are different!
So, I should change the port numbers to suitable numbers ...
After that, I have not the new IMAP emails!!
I was confused about this matter and finally, I found the solution that you see ...